# how to convert char array to multiple string indexes in java

Tags: java, string, arrays

I want to convert my char array to multiple string array's indexes. 
Like,

```
char[] c = {'a','n','i','k','s','m','r','j'};
```

I want it to be in a string and in a format like "anik", "sm" , "rj"

suppose I have a text file, and it is formatted like "anik" then in a new line "sm" and so on. I am reading it character by character and storing it in a char array, then want to convert it in the string of my question's format

help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Won't `String s1=c[0]+c[1]+c[2]+c[3]` and similarly others help?

Comment: How do you know where you have to "split" your `String` to get different "words" ?

Comment: what If it is for much bigger scenerio, I can't do index by index always..

suppose I have a text file, and it is formatted like "anik" then in a new line "sm" and so on. I am reading it character by character and storing it in a char array, then want to convert it in the string of my questio's format

Comment: Well it is going to depend what is the logic which determines what are the char which go together, in other words where to split like Florent said

Comment: If you are reading it from a file and each word is on its own line, you should probably read the whole line and store it in a String. No need for char reading

Comment: 1st, why you are reading in this way? Why don't you read full word(s) as string from text file?

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: if I store every words in string, how would I separate them in the format like "anik" "sm" and so on.

file's words are like

anik
sm
rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its  better if you use Scanner Class and read the file word by word:

```
Scanner s = null;
try {
    s= new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
    boolean b;
    while (b = s2.hasNext()) {
        String s1 = s2.next();
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @down voter  please give your reasons for downvote.

Comment: Does it solves your problem??

Comment: I hope you got the reason for downvoting,the edit says it all!!!

Comment: I am working on it. 
Seems great. Thank you.

Comment: @shekharsuman oh  yeah got it .Typos. But at least one should notify so that it can be edited.

Comment: After your edit,your downvote also was revised and converted to an upvote!Enjoy...